# Django raw queries and Postgres declare variable

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a file with many raw sql queries, that uses text substitution i.e

`select * from table1 where date_col between '%%from_date%%' and '%%to_date%%'`

these %%date_from%% and %%date_to%% are then replaced by values using python string replace function.
this works fine and the queries work.
however it is not ideal as it can be open to sql injection. (and no I can't use models or anything beside the raw sql) to make matters worse I can't use %s and parametrise the queries because the variables change order and %s works by order (as far as I can tell)

I thought about using declare in order to have my variables at the start of the select block i.e

```
sql - 
declare from_date date:= %s
declare to_date date:= %s
select * from table1 where date_col between to_date and from_date

python - 
with with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute(query, [from_date, to_date'])
```

but this gives out

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 1: DECLARE from_date date := '2022-01-01'::date DECLARE to_date...
                          ^
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'll be glad for some help. as far as I can see I got the syntax right, maybe django raw queries only support select? is there another way to make it work with parameterization ?
appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a top CTE to hold your variables, instead:

```
with invars as (
  select (%s)::date as from_date, (%s)::date as to_date
)
select *
  from invars i
       join table1 t 
         on t.date_col between i.to_date and i.from_date;
```

If the problem is that sometimes `from_date` and `to_date` are mixed up, then you can use [`BETWEEN SYMMETRIC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#:%7E:text=datatype%20BETWEEN%20SYMMETRIC%20datatype%20AND%20datatype%20%E2%86%92%20boolean).

If you need to use those variables in a query or another CTE that does not have anything to join to the `invars`, then use `cross join` to make `invar`'s columns available.

Comment: from_date and to_date are examples, there's about 10 variables spread around the queries :( although your workaround might work, I'm checking :D

Comment: @Cptmaxon  That `invars` CTE trick works really well in my experience--especially if you have variables that need to be used in multiple places in a large query.  Line them up like that, and it is easy to see whether your arguments tuple matches what the query expects.